# No Operating System after removing Windows

Tags: gparted

I tried to remove my windows partition and increase the ubuntu partition.

I used Gparted:

- Removed windows partition
- Increased Ubuntu partition (ext4)

I applied and it succeed.

But when I reboot my computer, I got no OS. No Ubuntu.
Just appear "Boot Menu"

1. SATA HDD
2. SATA CD

just that. I can't do anything with it

Why didn't I have my Ubuntu partition anymore?!

Because I do have an ext4 in the Gparted.

Do I need to reinstall a new Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Is this error from UEFI or BIOS? Is system UEFI or BIOS? What brand/model computer? May be best to see details. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: It is from BIOS

Comment: If you have not deleted the ubuntu OS partition, then you can restore the ability to boot.  See [GParted Manual - Fixing Operating System Boot Problems](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-fix-operating-system-boot-problems).  You might also look at the [GParted FAQ](http://gparted.org/faq.php).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Windows caused your Master Boot Record / GPT to behave aberrantly. You need to fix it so that it can locate the appropriate OS while booting.

1. Burn Ubuntu Live USB / DVD (You can do it via Unetbootin).
2. Boot the machine in Live Ubuntu environment.
3. Open up terminal and type

   `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \`

   `sudo apt-get update; \`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
4. Once the boot-repair window pops up , click on recommended repair.
5. Reboot.
   This might do the trick